# @Query Annotation doesn't fill and execute parameters

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using the Hibernate JPA with Spring Boot, and I am having a trouble returning results from a `CRUDRepository` where I have written a custom SQL query using the `@Query` tag. When I access the DAO and execute the method, it fires fine, but nothing is returned from the query.

```
public interface ContactRepository extends CrudRepository<Contact, BigInteger> {

    @Query(value ="SELECT * FROM all_contacts ac WHERE ac.userid= :userId " +
          "AND LOWER(ac.city) LIKE CONCAT('%', LOWER(:city), '%')",
          nativeQuery=true)
    List<Contact> findAllUserContactsByCityPartialMatch(@Param("city") String city, @Param("userId") BigInteger userId);

}
```

and when I fire off the code in a Model or Controller somewhere:

```
@Autowired
ContactRepository contactDAO

List<Contact> results = contactDAO.findAllUserContactsByCityPartialMatch("Chicago", 12345);
```

`results` will always be empty

My Logger tells me it's firing off this query:

```
SELECT * FROM all_contacts ac 
WHERE ac.userid= ? AND LOWER(ac.city) LIKE CONCAT('%', LOWER(?), '%')
```

I know the query is fine, because when I run the query and fill the fields manually in MySQL terminal, I get a result back.

```
SELECT * FROM all_contacts ac
WHERE ac.userid= 12345 AND LOWER(ac.city) LIKE CONCAT('%', LOWER("Chicago"), '%')`
```

Also, I know the DB is configured properly, because if I run say

```
Iterable<Contact> contactItr = contactDAO.findAll();
```

in the same model which was mentioned earlier, I get several persisted results back from the DB.

My thought is that it's not filling the parameters or executing them with the parameters in the `CRUDRepository` class, but I'm not sure. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named parameters are not supported in a native query in JPA. You can use positional parameters.

Also you could make use of JPA query language without `@Query` at all, something like:

```
public interface ContactRepository extends CrudRepository<Contact, BigInteger> {

    List<Contact> findAllByCityContainingIgnoreCaseAndUserId(String city, BigInteger userId);

}
```

Comment: Aha, that almost works, except that it generates an SQL query using a Like, but does not add any Wildcards, thus not returning any results. Shouldn't it be tossing in "%" 's? The end of a query like the one you wrote ends up being: `from all_contacts contact0_ where (upper(contact0_.city) like upper(?)) and contact0_.userid=?`

Comment: Ah, I was putting `"`'s around the search parameters from the client side where they were coming, so it wasn't adding the `%`'s properly. 

However, how would I search for partially completed numbers? Even just a "starts with" ? It seems to add the % in that case